# NEXTJS - Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'req.body' as it is undefined. (PATCH Method)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I try to get the information from the setting.js to do the PATCH Method but I get the error.

```
Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'req.body' as it is undefined.
```

In the setting I have another PUT method, to change password.
PUT method is working fine, but to edit name and bio, I try to use PATCH method but error.

How can I fix this problem?

Below are the code from setting.js and api/user/index.js

setting.js

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isUpdating) return;
    setIsUpdating(true);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', nameRef.current.value);
    formData.append('bio', bioRef.current.value);
    const res = await fetch('/api/user', {
      method: 'PATCH',
      body: formData,
    });
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const userData = await res.json();
      mutate({
        user: {
          ...user,
          ...userData.user,
        },
      });
      setMsg({ message: 'Profile updated' });
    } else {
      setMsg({ message: await res.text(), isError: true });
    }
  };
```

api/user/index.js

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import middleware from '../../../middlewares/middleware';
import { extractUser } from '../../../lib/api-helpers';

const handler = nextConnect();

handler.use(middleware);

handler.get(async (req, res) => res.json({ user: extractUser(req) }));

handler.patch(async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    req.status(401).end();
    return;
  }
  const { name, bio } = req.body;
  await req.db.collection('users').updateOne(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    {
      $set: {
        ...(name && { name }),
        bio: bio || '',
      },
    },
  );
  res.json({ user: { name, bio } });
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: Share the contents of `req.body`

Comment: Hi Evert, Thank you very much for your reply, since this methodology is quite new for me. Could you please show the example how to share the contents of req.body?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: It is 'undefined'.

Comment: Then your body is not getting sent, or not getting parsed. `bodyParser: false` is very suspicious =)

Comment: also change `req.status(401).end();` to `res` instead of `req`

Comment: @Evert Thank you very much, Evert. It's work fine but updateOne cannot update the content to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the config function which returns bodyParser as false. Because mentioning it as false stops parsing of the body from the request.

- I think you already solved the issue. But mentioning it.